# Give an O(N) algorithm to rearrange a list of true/false so that all false elements precede the true

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of N elements containing only two distinct keys, true and false.  I am trying to write an O(N) algorithm to rearrange the list so that all false elements precede the true elements.  A specific requirement for this algorithm is that I can only traverse the array once (meaning I can NOT make two traversals over the array; once to count the number of true/false's and another time to assign values into the array).  I am also not allowed to create an external temporary array.

Originally I wanted to use counting sort, but realized I could not do this since the requirement for this assignment is that I cannot create an external/temporary array.

Then, since there are only two possible values, I wanted to iterate through once and count them. Then Iterate through a second time and set the ordering (do the sort).  However, I cannot do this either because I am only allowed to do one iteration.

So I am on my own trying to implement an algorithm that will iterate only once through the array and sort at the same time.  So far what I have come up with is below (this is just an idea written more or less as pseudocode)

```
array = T T T T F F F F
int len = length of array.
counter = 0
For item in array
    counter += 1
    If counter <= len/2
       if T change to F
    else
       if F change to T
```

Right as I completed this, I realized that this only works when all the T values are on one side of the array, and all the F values are on the other.

My question is, can somebody tell me which O(n) sorting algorithm I can use to sort through each item in the array and arrange it so that all of the false elements precede the true?

Comment: If you iterate from the front and back simultaneously and stop when you meet in the middle, does that count as two iterations?

Comment: No, that would not count as two iterations.

Comment: Originally I wanted to use counting sort, but realized I could not do this since the requirement for this assignment is that I cannot create an extra/temporary array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an index (`lastFalseIdx`) where to insert a `False` element. So, initially it is 0. Traverse the array from left to right, and if `False` found, swap it with element at `lastFalseIdx`, and increment the index.

Python (almost pseudo-code):

```
arr = [True, True, False, False, False, True]

print arr

lastFalseIdx = 0

for idx, val in enumerate(arr):
    if val == False:
        arr[lastFalseIdx], arr[idx] = arr[idx], arr[lastFalseIdx]   # swap elements
        lastFalseIdx = lastFalseIdx + 1

print arr
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/isVgZD)

Comment: Can you explain in layman english what this code does?  I just want to be sure I follow correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the idea of the quick sort: walk through the array from the start and the end at the same time, and swap elements that have incorrect order. I.e. if you found `true` in the left half of the array, swap it with `false` in the right half.

Cause you have only 2 different values it's enough the single pass.

Example:

```
bool[] array = ...;
int low = 0;
int high = array.Length - 1;
do
{
    while (array[low] == false)
        low++;

    while (array[high] == true)
        high--;

    if (low <= high)
    {
        bool temp = array[low];
        array[low] = array[high];
        array[high] = temp;
    }
}
while (low < high);
```

This gives you exactly single pass, i.e. O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Concisely:

```
swap = 0
for index in range(len(list)):
    if list[index] != true:
        list[index], list[swap] = list[swap], list[index]
        swap += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial solution that constructs the correct output in a separate array. You can infer an inline implementations by observing what happens when you initialize `output = input` instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

input = [False, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False]

def sort2(input):
    i_false = 0
    i_true = len(input) - 1

    output = [None] * len(input)
    for (i, val) in enumerate(input):
        if val:
            output[i_true]  = True
            i_true -= 1
        else:
            output[i_false] = False
            i_false += 1
    return output

print sort2(input)
```

After a single forward pass through the array, you have the desired output.

Comment: I like the idea of this, but does this put all false elements at the front?  From what I can tell, this only changes the F to T and T to F.

Comment: @OmarN: It doesn't change anything, rather, it positions the values at the correct place in the output array. The implementation in Python is probably more readable than the text description.

Answer (score -1):

hope the below answer helps.

```
internal void ArrangeBooleanArray()
    {
        bool[] inputArray = {false, true, true, false};
        int arrayLength = inputArray.Length;
        bool[] outputArray = new bool[arrayLength];
        int trueCount = 0;
        int falseCount = 0;            

        foreach (var item in inputArray)
        {
            if (item == true)
            {
                trueCount++;
                outputArray[arrayLength - trueCount] = item;                    
            }
            else
            {
                outputArray[falseCount] = item;
                falseCount++;
            }
        }
    }
```